# Refactor this function to reduce its Cognitive Complexity - Tagged as Critical issue

Tags: python, sonarqube

I am using SonarQube Version – 6.7.7(LTS) and Python language analyzer plugin version - `sonar-python-plugin-1.13.0.2922.jar`.

Completed the sonar analysis successfully, then I could see “Refactor this function to reduce its Cognitive Complexity from 17 to the 15 allowed” related issues being tagged as Critical issue.

[image]

I feel this issue should go under Major (or) Minor category but not as Critical issue.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Is this behavior is correct?

Comment: That’s the default. https://rules.sonarsource.com/python/RSPEC-3776 You can probably configure it if you prefer a different severity.

Comment: Under Rules--> Python--> Code Smell-->  Cognitive Complexity of functions should not be too high --> Critical - shows as Default Severity. I’m unable to change the severity to minor.

Answer (score 1):

You should define your own quality profile to customize the severity of that rule. See the [documentation on quality profiles](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/instance-administration/quality-profiles/).